# What is the word for a collection of "adverb", "verb", "noun", etc...?

Tags: word-request

I'm looking for a word that means a set of words such as "noun", "adverb", "adjective", "verb", "preposition", "conjunction", etc...

What is the proper word to mean that? If I search for it in my native language I got *"a part of speech"*, but feel that there is a word.

Comment: We often use the term 'category" as an alternant to 'part of speech'.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about a single word. A more technical term that doesn't mean *precisely* the same as "parts of speech" is ***syntactic category***. If you only want the categories that apply to individual words, not to phrases, you can use ***lexical categories***.